# Dynamically adding items to a List<T> through reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Lets say I have this class

```
class Child {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Container {
    public List<Child> { get; set; }
}
```

I'm working on a deserializer of sorts and I want to be able to create and populate the `Child` list from the data retrieved. I've gotten this far (I've cut out a lot of handling for other types for this example so its unnecessarily "iffy" but bear with me):

```
var props = typeof(Container).GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in props) {
    var type = prop.PropertyType;
    var name = prop.Name;

    if (type.IsGenericType) {
        var t = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        if (type == typeof(List<>)) {
            var list = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var elements = GetElements();

            foreach (var element in elements) {
                var item = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                Map(item, element); 

                // ??? how do I do list.Add(item) here?
            }

            prop.SetValue(x, list, null); // x is an instance of Container

        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to cast `list` to essentially `List<t.GetType()>` so I can access the add method and add the item.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say you should cast down to `System.Collections.IList` and directly call the Add method.  Pros: simple, no ugly reflection.  Cons: causes boxing for Lists containing value types.

Answer (score 19):

This should work unless I am really missing something.

**Outside of the loop**

```
var add = type.GetMethod("Add");
```

**Inside the loop**

```
add.Invoke(list, new[] { item });
```

Comment: This is a good answer and I appreciate your response so +1. bobbymcr's works though and doesn't use reflection so I'm going with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `type.MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments())`, which will return the correct closed generic type. You would then need to reflectively call the `Add` method. The code should look something like this:

```
   Type listType = type.MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments());
   MethodInfo addMethod = listType.GetMethod("Add");
   addMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { ... });
```

I'm not sure what you would use as `instance`, but this is the actual object on which the method will be invoked.

The better question to ask is why are you trying to do this? The .NET Framework already includes serializers that know how to do all of this type of work. If you can, you should be using one of those instead of trying to "roll your own".

Comment: I knew someone would ask "why?" XmlSerializer has some limitations (doesn't support List<T> most notably) and the other options I explored were too verbose for this project (which is going to be a framework, so if it operates at a little lower level, it's fine with me). Basically in order to achieve simplicity I'm looking for, I have to roll my own.

Comment: @John Sheehan: Why is the resulting serialized data intersting/important to you? There are other serializers available than just XmlSerializer, such as the WCF data contract serializer. It can easily be used and supports `List<T>`. Yes, it can generate some ugly looking XML, but in general that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I don't need an serializing, only deserializing and I don't want to use any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i do

```
    var genericType = _primaryType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
    IList o = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    o.Add(x)
```