# Build Expression tree to Add elements to Collection dynamically c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, reflection, expression-trees

I have a class and I need to iterate tru each property reading the attribute name to map to my data Source the value, in the cases where I have a ICollection that property will have multiple attributes to map the correct value.

I'm using Expression trees to set the values efficiently to each property but I'm having issues to set the values to the Collection.
I think this is because I need to create an instance of that Collection but I don't know. I'm a bit lost on that one here's what I got:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MapToAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MapToAttribute(string field)
    {
        Field = field;
    }

    public string Field { get; private set; }
}

public class MyDataClass
{
    [MapTo("one")]
    public int propOne { get; set; }

    [MapTo("two")]
    public string propTwo { get; set; }

    [MapTo("item1")]
    [MapTo("item2")]
    [MapTo("item3")]
    public ICollection<int> collection { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var setter = SetValues<MyDataClass>();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> SetValues<T>()
        where T : new()
    {
        var properties = GetClassProperties<T>();
        var results = new List<T>();

        for (int x = 1; x<=100; x++)
        {
            var row = new T();

            //Simulated Datasource
            var dataSource = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dataSource.Add("one", x);
            dataSource.Add("two", x.ToString());
            dataSource.Add("item1", x);
            dataSource.Add("item2", x+x);
            dataSource.Add("item3", x*x); 

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                //this line executes the Action
                property.Value(row, dataSource[property.Key]);
            }
            results.Add(row);
        }
        return results;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>> GetClassProperties<T>()
    {
        var setters = new Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>>();

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var names = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapToAttribute), true)
                .Select(p => ((MapToAttribute)p).Field);

            var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(
                  Expression.Call(
                        instance,
                        property.GetSetMethod(),
                        Expression.Convert(argument, property.PropertyType)
                  ), instance, argument
                ).Compile();

          // Due to the types I cannot just assign a value to a ICollection,
          // that's why I tried to create HERE a different setter 
          // when the property Type is ICollection, I commented out the code failing.
          
            //var getCollection = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
            //        Expression.Call(
            //            instance,
            //            prop.GetGetMethod()
            //        ), instance
            //      ).Compile();

            //Action<T, object> setter = (classInstance, value) =>  
            // getCollection(classInstance).Add(value);


            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                setters.Add(name, setter);
            } 
        }

        return setters;
    }
}
```

Comment: This post deals with `List<T>` but I believe you can apply the logic to your scenario as `ICollection` has a `.Add(T)` method. Perhaps this will help you: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546905/dynamically-adding-items-to-a-listt-through-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all to make life easier you will need to initialize collection:

```
public ICollection<int> collection { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

Second try this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>> GetClassProperties<T>()
{
    var setters = new Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>>();

    var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var names = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapToAttribute), true)
            .Select(p => ((MapToAttribute)p).Field)
            .ToList();
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType) // start checking that prop implements ICollection
        {
            // get ICollection generic parameter type
            var genericParam = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
            // construct concrete ICollection type
            var propColType = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(genericParam);
            if (propColType.IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)) // check if is ICollection of genericParam 
            {
                var getCollection = Expression.Call(instance, property.GetGetMethod());
                var addMethod = propColType.GetMethod("Add");    
                var colAddSetter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(
                    Expression.Call(getCollection, addMethod, Expression.Convert(argument, genericParam)),
                    instance, argument)
                .Compile();
                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    setters.Add(name, colAddSetter);
                }
                continue; // process next property
            }
        }

        // process "ordinary" property
        var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(
              Expression.Call(
                    instance,
                    property.GetSetMethod(),
                    Expression.Convert(argument, property.PropertyType)
              ), instance, argument
            ).Compile();

        setters.Add(names.Single(), setter); // todo throw normal exception instead of Single
    }

    return setters;
}
```